# How to repeat random string with .repeat() and make it still random?

Tags: javascript

Is there some way to make random strings with `.repeat()` still random? If I use this:

```
console.log(`${Math.random()} | `.repeat(5));
```

the output is something like this:

```
0.2564646392254777 | 0.2564646392254777 | 0.2564646392254777 | 0.2564646392254777 | 0.2564646392254777 |
```

In a nutshell, the output is the same.

Comment: Do you really need the `|` at the end ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your code currently does is:

1. Generate a random number within a string
2. Repeat `n` times that string.

What you want is generate `n` random number strings, *then* join them.

Here is a function that does this:

```js
function randomNumberString(n) {
    return Array(n).fill(0).map(_ => `${Math.random()}`).join(' | ');
}
console.log(randomNumberString(10));
```

And if you really want the `|` at the end:

```js
function randomNumberString(n) {
    return Array(n).fill(0).map(_ => `${Math.random()} | `).join('');
}
console.log(randomNumberString(10));
```